# PostgreSQL - Insert all weekend dates from year xxxx to year yyyy

Tags: postgresql, generate-series, set-returning-functions

I have already built a holidays table containing all public holidays from 2000 to 2050. But I have should have put also all weekend dates and now I am trying to find an approach to it. Can somebody suggest something? I checked and there are functions for calculating the number of the business days, but I need insertion of all weekends between these two years.

Answer (score 4):

If 8.4+:

```
select 
    a::date as Sunday, 
    a::date - 1 as Saturday
from generate_series('2000-01-02'::date, '2050-12-31', '7 days') s(a)
;
```

Else:

```
select 
    '2000-01-02'::date + s.a as Sunday, 
    '2000-01-02'::date + s.a - 1 as Saturday
from generate_series(0, '2050-12-31'::date - '2000-01-02'::date, 7) s(a)
;
```